# Is it possible to control the direction of the facebook like button comment popout?

Tags: facebook, widget, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I would like the popout to go to the left instead of the right if possible, as it's sometimes hidden by other UI elements.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since it's a social plugin, the only styling you can change is what you see on the [plugin configuration page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).